# Hashing and security measures in PHP

Tags: php, security, bcrypt, sha512

I have read about how to implement security into a website using hashing, and I am not creating something terribly sensitive like a bank or storing credit cards. I would, however, like to know the best practices. My site has a TLS cert with AES 256

Main issues:

1.) Sending the hashed password hashed again through the session seems to be the only way I can think of to keep the session fairly secure. In my opinion, I don't really care if the user finds that value, but I would care if the user found some way to see the database and knew exactly what my encryption algo was.

2.) Should I just completely take out my algorithm prior to hashing the password, or should I use different hashing methods?

Is it okay to use sha512 prior or after bcrypt, since both of these are sound as far as collisions and brute force?

Comment: A (really) good method of generating hashes is to multiply it by some sort of time algorithm, like "60x60x24" or something. Personally, I use some decimals like "1.02401 x seconds x minutes x hours" All of this ON TOP of the current system you have in place. You could also use a private key as your seed, which you should protect with your life, or at least change it once a week.

Comment: what do you mean by multiply it?

Comment: do you mean incorporate the time into the original hashing? if so, how would you check it against the db?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use time as mesh suggested, as to reproduce the time it would need to be stored in the database (which defeats the purpose of using it). For generating hash you'd need a reproducible value (hardcoded or something not stored in the database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I just SHA512 passwords for storage and comparison upon login, and for session tracking I store a key of `hash('sha512', $username.$salt.$password);`, this key is stored in the session and compared against the user's key in the database to authenticate their session.

I've yet to come across any security issues with this, it shouldn't be possible to forge a key unless you know the user's username, password and their user salt (which obviously should not be stored in the database) so it should be secure as long as someone doesn't get access to both your database and your code (in which case you've got bigger issues than protecting user passwords ;))

Comment: yes, that is not a bad idea. the whole point of me creating my own algo was to create a unique salt, but who is to say that it doesnt have any collisions? I hoped that it wouldn't since its all concatenated. In my opinion, if it did have collisions, that would be almost negligibly useful.

Comment: What I usually do for a salt is store the timestamp of when the user logs in then combine that with a hard-coded salt, hash the salt with the username and password, then store it in the session. This way the salt is unique for every login, so even if some malicious person manages to get their hands on the key, it's only valid until the next time the user logs in (because when they login next it'll make a new timestamp thus a new unique session key)